# The maximum number of frames per second in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Documentation from `UIKit` says:

> On iOS the maximum number of frames per second is typically 60.

After the release of the new iPhones 13 Pro with 120Hz support, I asked myself:

1. How can I check the maximum FPS in `SwiftUI`?
2. How do I change the FPS limit in my `SwiftUI` app?

For the `UIKit` *world* I found the `maximumFramesPerSecond` property in `UIScreen`, but nothing similar for `SwiftUI`.

Can someone explain these questions to me?

Comment: It's all automatic, you shouldn't need to change the FPS for your app

Comment: I was just reading an article that says, for iPhones 13 Pro with 120Hz support,
Apple currently ensures that third-party apps cannot use the 120Hz refresh rate for animations,
it's limited to 60Hz. Apparently scrolling and full-screen transitions for example can use 120Hz.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with `SwiftUI` but here's a solution for macOS:

```
if let mode = CGDisplayCopyDisplayMode(CGMainDisplayID())
{
  let curRefreshRate = mode.refreshRate
  ...
}
```

Potentially you could use `UIScreen.maximumFramesPerSecond` on iOS and `CGDisplayMode.refreshRate` on macOS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CADisplayLink to fire a method with every screen refresh. You can check the time interval between refreshes to determine the hz.

I wonder how it works on a Pro Motion display when content is static, since the hz should go down. I don't have one so I can't test.

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-synchronize-code-to-drawing-using-cadisplaylink